# Convert an integer column to Month type MM

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use `PRECEDING` and `FOLLOWING` on ranged month with following code

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
SELECT location.city,  date.date, COUNT(*) OVER W 
FROM fact, crime, date, location 
WHERE fact.location_key = location.location_key and crime.crime_key = 
fact.crime_key and fact.date_key = date.date_key
WINDOW W AS (
            PARTITION BY location.city, date.year
            ORDER BY date.month
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1 month' PRECEDING
            AND INTERVAL '1 month' FOLLOWING
        ))
```

I got the error says

```
RANGE with offset PRECEDING/FOLLOWING is not supported for column type integer and offset type interval
```

I assume this is because my `date.month` is of type integer

So I tried to convert my `date.month` column to date type of format `MM`

I tried following

```
ALTER TABLE date ALTER COLUMN month TYPE text 
 using to_date(month, 'MM');
```

and gives error

```
 No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My question is

How to convert `date.month` to a type that can be used with `PROCEDING` and `FOLLOWING` command ?

I assume this type is `date` with format `MM`. That's why I tried the above code

Thank you!

Comment: Please, check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) first and provide you attempt.

Comment: You say you want to convert an int to a data, but there is no date in your sample data.

Comment: Date types don't have a format.  Your question is very unclear.  What results do you want?

Comment: If you want to format the number using to digit, you should be using `to_char(month, 'FM00')` and there is no need to change the column type for that. Just apply the formatting when you display the value.

Comment: `select case when Month<10 then '0'||Month::text else Month::text end from table` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff   Sorry for confusion, I edited my question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Sorry, I'm planning to use ```date.month``` as a date type in my other queries, that's why I want to convert my ```date.month``` to date type, I edited my question

Comment: @GMB Sorry, I mean to convert my ```date.month``` to a type that can be used in ```PRECEDING```  and  ```FOLLOWING``` commmand, I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert `month` column to any other datatype. The windowing clause i.e `rows between...` in your case works on a given partition which is `PARTITION BY location.city, date.year`. You need to add `month` to partition clause first in order for it to work in the window clause. Also don't use old style of joining.

```
WITH tmp1 AS (
SELECT location.city,  date.date, COUNT(*) OVER W 
FROM fact
join crime
on crime.crime_key = fact.crime_key
join date
on fact.date_key = date.date_key 
join location 
on fact.location_key = location.location_key and 
WINDOW W AS (
            PARTITION BY location.city, date.year, date.month
            ORDER BY date.month
            RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING
            AND 1 FOLLOWING
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use an interval range when you can use an integer range?

```
WINDOW W AS (
        PARTITION BY location.city, date.year
        ORDER BY date.month
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 PRECEDING AND
                      INTERVAL 1 FOLLOWING
       )
```